# Python mud kill function

Tags: python, mud

I'm trying to make a MUD using  [MUD-PI](https://github.com/Frimkron/mud-pi) and I'm stuck at making rooms contain monsters and having the kill command know what monster to calculate the attack for

Here is my code for the kill command

```
  `elif command == "kill":

        if players[id]["room"]["enemy"] == 'True':
            if players[id]["room"]["monsterName"].hp >= 0:
                mud.send_message(id,"You attack %s for %d damage" % (players[id]["room"]["monsterName"], players[id]["ATK"]))
                players[id]["room"]["monsterName"].hp -= players[id]["ATK"]
            else:
                players[id]["room"]["monsterName"].death()
        else:
            mud.send_message(id,"You dont see a monster")]
```

and the code for the rooms

```
#import monsters
from Monsters import *
# structure defining the rooms in the game. Try adding more rooms to the game!
rooms = {
    "Tavern": {
        "description": "You're in a cozy tavern warmed by an open fire.",
        "exits": { "outside": "Outside" },
    },
    "Outside": {
        "description": "You're standing outside a tavern. there is a troll.",
        "exits": { "inside": "Tavern" },
        "enemy": 'True',
        "monsterName": troll,
    }
}
```

and finally the monster code

```
#monsters

import sys,random,os,time

#Troll
class Troll():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Troll"
        self.ATK = 2
        self.hp = 10
        self.max_hp = 10

    def death(self):
        mud.send_message(id,"you killed the troll")
        self.hp = self.max_hp


troll = Troll()
```

When I try the current code I get this error:

```
if players[id]["room"]["enemy"] == 'True':
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I would like to know what is causing this error and if possible, how I can get this to work the way I want.

EDIT: I got this to work but when i use the command in the game it comes out like this ( You attack  ) for 3 damage
I would like it to say you attacked the name of the monster in the room.

here is my edited code

```
elif command == "kill":
             rm = rooms[players[id]["room"]]

             if rm["enemy"] == 'yes':
                 if rm["monsterName"].hp >= 0:
                     mud.send_message(id,"You attack %s for %d damage" % (rm["monsterName"], players[id]["ATK"]))
                     rm["monsterName"].hp -= players[id]["ATK"]
                 else:
                     rm["monsterName"].death()
             else:
                 mud.send_message(id,"You dont see a monster")
```

I would like to also change the command from kill to kill [monsterName] in this case troll, i tried to do so like this

```
elif command == "kill":
            mn = params.lower()
            rm = rooms[players[id]["room"]]
            if rm["enemy"] == 'yes':

                if mn in rm["monsterName"]:
                    monster = rm["monsterName"]
                    if monster.hp >= 0:
                        mud.send_message(id,"You attack %s for %d damage" % (rm["monsterName"], players[id]["ATK"]))
                        monster.hp -= players[id]["ATK"]
                    else:
                        monster.death()
                else:
                    mud.send_message(id, "you dont see a %s" % mn)
            else:
                mud.send_message(id, "you dont see an enemy")
```

but when i try to use it i get this error

```
 if mn in rm["monsterName"]:
TypeError: argument of type 'instance' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added the `enemy` key to the `rooms` data structure (i.e., dictionary), but when you access `players[id]["room"]["enemy"]` you are *not* accessing the `rooms` data structure -- you are accessing `players`, and in `players` the `room` value is a string -- the name of the room. So you cannot ask for its "enemy" index, since that would be meaningless, and this is the source of the error `string indices must be integers, not str`.

To fix the error in the code as it is designed currently, you must find the room the player is in and then access the *room's* "enemy" value, and in a similar fashion find the value for the `monsterName`.

Comment: when i tried your advice it worked but the name of the troll comes out as <Monsters.Troll instance at 0x0264D440> for 3 damage

Comment: @Arcxes, the way this site works it's better to ask smaller, self-contained questions than put all your questions under one topic with a generic title like "Python mud kill function". Currently your question is hard to follow and no one can guess what you asked from the title. I recommend you accept my answer if it answered your questions, then break out this new problem into a new question with a more descriptive title.